# How to enable ActiveX controls in firefox?

Tags: firefox, activex, selenium

I have an application which uses ActiveX controls. I want to automate this using Selenium IDE. But when i launch the application i end up in an error message "Turn on you ActiveX control". Is there any way to enable ActiveX in FireFox?

Note: I am using User Agent Switcher(as IE7) Addon of firefox to run my application.

Answer (score 1):

No. [Firefox doesn't support ActiveX](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/ActiveX).

Answer (score 1):

"ff-activex-host" worked for me. It uses different  tag, but otherwise seems to work on both firefox and chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can look around the [MediaWrap](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/1879) extension for firefox. It is supposed to add transparent ActiveX support to Firefox.

I am not sure it already works with firefox 3.6 though and there are known limitations.

Maybe you can give it a try.

Jerome Wagner

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [MeadCo's Neptune](http://www.meadroid.com/neptune/download/).

Or this: [IE Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ie-tab-2-ff-36).